Post-apocalyptic movie where people can't or don't speak
I've seen the trailer but can't remember the title. It's a newer film (within the past 10-15 years I'd guess) and it seemed to be mostly set in the woods. As stated in title, people can't/won't/don't speak for some reason.
I believe the lead is a female character and she's to be sacrificed (shackled in chains perhaps) to some dark figure - a horrible creature, or maybe a man in an animal mask? with antlers?? But she escapes and I think most of the movie is about her flight/fight for survival.  She may have a rifle as her only defense/weapon.

I see you've ID it as Azrael, but a close contender would be Bone Tomahawk (2015) - It's only the cannabalistic Troglodites who don't speak, the rest of the characters do. Lead is male (Kurt Russell) and he sets out to rescue a female character. Quite grim and very violent watching.

That sounds like Azrael, with Samara Weaving. It's got silent characters because their vocal cords were removed, demons, is set in the woods, and the movie is about Samara's character fighting for survival after escaping being sacrificed. It only came out this year though.
Trailer




THANK YOU! That's it exactly (I thought it was a newer movie, but went wide on the age estimate just to be safe)
